# Spring Boot Email Microservice not working on Swarm Mode

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-swarm

I have a spring boot + email configured microservice.

I have an issue where I am able to deploy my email microservice to docker directly in a VM, and it connects to my email and sends emails to different inboxes.

However, as soon as I deploy the same microservice in a docker swarm mode, in the same VM, the micro service doesn't connect to my email and is thus not able to send emails. The microservice is not able to resolve the email host and give a timeout exception. What do I need to change in order to have the connection happening?

My docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  email-api:
    image: xxx/email-api:1.0.0
    ports:
      - "8081:8080"
    environment:
      - EUREKA_SERVER=http://192.168.99.105:8761/eureka
    networks:
      - network-eureka
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      update_config:
        parallelism: 2
        delay: 10s
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 120s
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == worker]

networks:
  network-eureka:

volumes:
  mongo_email_data:
    external: true
```

Below is the log file when attempting to connect:

```
dev-broker_brokercrm-email-api.1.r0dl707sue42@local-broker-swarm-3    | 2020-02-24 19:14:27.409 TRACE 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] com.sun.mail.util.socket                 : connection failed
dev-broker_brokercrm-email-api.1.r0dl707sue42@local-broker-swarm-3    |
dev-broker_brokercrm-email-api.1.r0dl707sue42@local-broker-swarm-3    | java.net.UnknownHostException: mail.nguni52.co.za
dev-broker_brokercrm-email-api.1.r0dl707sue42@local-broker-swarm-3    |     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
dev-broker_brokercrm-email-api.1.r0dl707sue42@local-broker-swarm-3    |     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
dev-broker_brokercrm-email-api.1.r0dl707sue42@local-broker-swarm-3    |     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
dev-broker_brokercrm-email-api.1.r0dl707sue42@local-broker-swarm-3    |     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
dev-broker_brokercrm-email-api.1.r0dl707sue42@local-broker-swarm-3    |     at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:359) [javax.mail-1.6.2.jar!/:1.6.2]
dev-broker_brokercrm-email-api.1.r0dl707sue42@local-broker-swarm-3    |     at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:238) [javax.mail-1.6.2.jar!/:1.6.2]
dev-broker_brokercrm-email-api.1.r0dl707sue42@local-broker-swarm-3    |     at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2175) [javax.mail-1.6.2.jar!/:1.6.2]
dev-broker_brokercrm-email-api.1.r0dl707sue42@local-broker-swarm-3    |     at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:740) [javax.mail-1.6.2.jar!/:1.6.2]
dev-broker_brokercrm-email-api.1.r0dl707sue42@local-broker-swarm-3    |     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366) [javax.mail-1.6.2.jar!/:1.6.2]
dev-broker_brokercrm-email-api.1.r0dl707sue42@local-broker-swarm-3    |     at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.connectTransport(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:517) [spring-context-support-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
dev-broker_brokercrm-email-api.1.r0dl707sue42@local-broker-swarm-3    |     at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:436) [spring-context-support-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
dev-broker_brokercrm-email-api.1.r0dl707sue42@local-broker-swarm-3    |     at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:360) [spring-context-support-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
dev-broker_brokercrm-email-api.1.r0dl707sue42@local-broker-swarm-3    |     at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:377) [spring-context-support-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
dev-broker_brokercrm-email-api.1.r0dl707sue42@local-broker-swarm-3    |     at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:365) [spring-context-support-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
dev-broker_brokercrm-email-api.1.r0dl707sue42@local-broker-swarm-3    |     at com.antech.broker.crm.email.service.EmailService.sendNewUserEmail(EmailService.java:174) [classes!/:1.0.0]
dev-broker_brokercrm-email-api.1.r0dl707sue42@local-broker-swarm-3    |     at com.antech.broker.crm.email.controller.EmailController.sendNewUserEmail(EmailController.java:177) [classes!/:1.0.0]
dev-broker_brokercrm-email-api.1.r0dl707sue42@local-broker-swarm-3    |     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
dev-broker_brokercrm-email-api.1.r0dl707sue42@local-broker-swarm-3    |     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
dev-broker_brokercrm-email-api.1.r0dl707sue42@local-broker-swarm-3    |     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
dev-broker_brokercrm-email-api.1.r0dl707sue42@local-broker-swarm-3    |     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
dev-broker_brokercrm-email-api.1.r0dl707sue42@local-broker-swarm-3    |     at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) [spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
dev-broker_brokercrm-email-api.1.r0dl707sue42@local-broker-swarm-3    |     at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) [spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
dev-broker_brokercrm-email-api.1.r0dl707sue42@local-broker-swarm-3    |     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) [spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
dev-broker_brokercrm-email-api.1.r0dl707sue42@local-broker-swarm-3    |     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892) [spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
dev-broker_brokercrm-email-api.1.r0dl707sue42@local-broker-swarm-3    |     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) [spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
dev-broker_brokercrm-email-api.1.r0dl707sue42@local-broker-swarm-3    |     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) [spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEAS
```

Comment: Where is the docker.yml file ? where is container logs?

Comment: Will edit the question and provide both.

Comment: It seems to have a connection failuer to `com.sun.mail.util.socket`, is it an external connection ? if so maybe somthing is blocking connection.  try from your host to mybe telnet this ip